# C# Windows Azure Mobile Services - Get response from server after insert

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-runtime, response, azure-mobile-services

I try to insert an object into a table on windows azure mobile services and get the "request.response". But I have no real idea of how do that.

Update : 
I catch something when I did something worng with this, but I still have no idea how to catch when it's a success :

```
 catch (Exception w)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(w.ToString());

        }
```

EndUpdate.

I keep looking a solution on my own but if anyone have an idea, it's with pleasure.

Thanks for your time,

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if the absence of failure isn't good enough to mark success :) you can get access to the request and response stream by using a [DelegatingHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx), which is a rather new addition to Windows Azure Mobile Services (but not the .NET HTTP stack) and supersedes Service filters ([IServiceFilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.delegatinghandler.aspx), et. al.)

The documentation for the constructor of [MobileServicesClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.aspx) doesn't show it, but the optional fourth+ parameters are a chain of [HttpMessageHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpmessagehandler.aspx) via which you can access the HTTP pipelines.

The best example I could find of this in the context of Windows Azure Mobile services is on [Carlos Figueira's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/03/14/azure-mobile-services-managed-client-upcoming-breaking-changes.aspx) - skip down to the section labeled **Service filters -> HttpClient primitives**